# AWS RDS Extension Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to enable some Postgres extensions to specific user in AWS RDS Postgres instance.

**1) I have tried through deployment using rails migration, didnt work.**

```
class InstallPgTrgmContribPackage < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    enable_extension "fuzzystrmatch"
    enable_extension "pg_trgm"
    enable_extension "unaccent"

    # execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;"
    # execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;"
    # execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent;"
  end
end
```

**2) Also, tried through ssh-ing into postgres and create it from there.**

```
psql -h blabla.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U prod -d prod

prod=> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;
returns: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "fuzzystrmatch"
          HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

> By default RDS instance role is test, and I am able to create
> extension in test user. I am trying to install in prod and dev users.

[image]

The rails application deployed through Elastic Beanstalk.

**Question:** How to add superuser privileges into new user role?

Comment: Test user is rds_superuser member, how can i make dev and prod member of rds_superuser ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Trying to create `pg_trgm` extension in dev and prod user roles, and it returns `Must be superuser to create this extension`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the prod user does not have superuser priviledges:

As stated from AWS Docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html

```
1. create role testuser with password 'testuser' login;   
   CREATE ROLE   

2. grant rds_superuser to testuser;   
   GRANT ROLE
```

Point 1 has already been done as there is a prod user

Thus, you need to run point 2 command to grant priviledges.

Comment: I dunno, how's happen this. I have tried this way also, but works now. Thx. Do you know how to connect to user role if doesnt have database ?

Comment: Using the below mentioned command you can connect to postgres using username without any db

psql \
   --host=<DB instance endpoint> \
   --port=<port> \
   --username=<master user name> \
   --password \